# Python: what's an elegant way to select specific rows of an 2-d array into a new array?

Tags: python, arrays

For example, given a python numpy.ndarray `a = array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]])`, I want to select the 0th and 2nd row of array `a` into a new array `b`, such that `b` becomes `array([[1,2],[5,6]]`.

I need to solution to work on more general problems, where the original 2d array can have more rows and I should be able to select the rows based on some disjoint ranges. In general, I was looking for something like `a[i:j] + a[k:p]` that works for 1-d list, but it seems 2d-arrays won't add up this way.

**update**
It seems that I can use `vstack((a[i:j], a[k:p]))` to get this working, but is there any elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use list indexing:

```
a[ [0,2], ]
```

More generally, to select rows `i:j` and `k:p` (I'm assuming in the python sense, meaning rows i to j but not including j):

```
a[ range(i,j) + range(k,p)   , ]
```

Note that the `range(i,j) + range(k,p)` creates a *flat* list of `[ i, i+1, ..., j-1, k, k+1, ..., p-1 ]`, which is then used to index the rows of `a`.

Comment: +1  i find tuples usually look less strange for fancy indexing though.

Answer (score 3):

`numpy` is kind of clever when it comes to indexing. You can give it a list of indexes and it will return the sliced part.

```
In : a = numpy.array([[i]*10 for i in range(10)])

In : a
Out:
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
       [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
       [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5],
       [6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6],
       [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7],
       [8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8],
       [9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9]])

In : a[[0,5,9]]
Out:
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5],
       [9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9]])

In : a[range(0,2)+range(5,8)]
Out:
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5],
       [6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6],
       [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7]])
```